# Perforce Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 on Ubuntu 12.04(64) can not retrieve clients

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perforce, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to configure eclipse 3.7 with Perforce P4 Plugin. 
When I try to create a connection with :
Server: 
User: 
Instead of searching only clients for '' - the plugin tries to
search all possible clients, on the p4 console in eclipse, I see that
the command issued is:
'p4 clients' - it should be - 'p4 clients -u user'

I have created the following environment variables - P4PORT, P4USER, P4CLIENT. I see that people with Ubuntu 10.04(64) are not facing this problem. I am not able to find out from where the perforce plugin reads and uses value of P4USER while issuing "p4 clients" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Perforce plugin for 3.6 in both Eclispe 3.7 and 4.2 and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you usually specify your Perforce user name when you configure a connection to Perforce.  Probably best to ask Perforce support to sort it out for you.